# NSHashTable retaining weak reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

So, apple's documentation for `[NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable]` states:

> Returns a new hash table for storing weak references to its contents.

So, when I run the following code...

```
NSHashTable *hashTable = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
ABC *object = [[ABC alloc] init];
[hashTable addObject:object];
NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);
object = nil;
NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);
```

The output is:

```
2017-09-18 12:57:02.801 Test2[6912:640614] <ABC: 0x608000014eb0>
2017-09-18 12:57:02.801 Test2[6912:640614] <ABC: 0x608000014eb0>
2017-09-18 12:57:02.803 Test2[6912:640614] dealloc // (dealloc of ABC)
```

It looks like calling `NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);` is retaining the object.

If I call,

```
NSHashTable *hashTable = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
ABC *object = [[ABC alloc] init];
[hashTable addObject:object];
//NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);
object = nil;
NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);
```

The ouput is as expected:

```
2017-09-18 13:00:23.949 Test2[6936:645459] dealloc
2017-09-18 13:00:23.949 Test2[6936:645459] (null)
```

Can someone tell me where my misunderstanding is?

Comment: It shouldn't happen. When are you po in debugger? I hope the debug pointer is after object = nil; statement.

Comment: Well that's weird. It is doing it now. I could have sworn that I was printing after setting object to nil, but I guess I was off. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the code and it is certainly weird. If I po just after adding the object in hashTable and then po after object = nil, the object seems to get retained. Trying it with NSLog now, may be its a  debugger bug.

Comment: Even with the NSLog the issue is there. I will try to find the reason.

Comment: @PuneetSharma I wonder if it's being retained by the debugger. Because if I put a print statement in the dealloc of my SOQuestionObject, it prints when I let it run normally, but when I step through it with the debugger, dealloc is never called. 
Possible relevant side info: I'm testing this in a console application

Comment: @joellisup: Try this code, with no debugger. Its printing objects both times. Should not happen though. NSHashTable *hashTable = [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable];
    ABC *object = [[ABC alloc] init];
    [hashTable addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);
    object = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@", [hashTable anyObject]);

Comment: There is certainly an issue here. May I edit your question?

Comment: You may edit it. You've been very helpful in helping in me work through this. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't even have to call NSLog — just doing [hashTable anyObject] is enough to make the object stick around. The reason seems to be that anyObject returns an autoreleased reference, which does not get release:d until some point in the future. Wrap the whole thing in an @autorelease block, and I believe it will work as expected.

Generally speaking, it is dangerous to make assumptions about exactly when an ARC:ed object will be released, because there is lots of magic like this going on.

Comment: Indeed, that is the reason. Thanks

Comment: That's wierd, the autoreleased object won't be released even exiting the current method's scope.